# pass data back to a jQuery Plugin's caller element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

As an exercise in learning js, I am building a color picker plugin for jQuery. I have a bootstrap modal that is displayed (Click Me). When a color is selected in the modal I would like to set the button (the button that opened the modal) background to the button that was clicked in the modal. I can't figure out how to access the parent without resorting to using unique id's or any other bootstrap functionality.

Here's what I have so far (sorry, couldnt get jsfiddle to load) plugin code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.colorpicker = function(options) {


        var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.colorpicker.defaults, options );
        var colorContainer = $('<ul/>').attr('id', 'container');
            $(opts.colors).each( function( index) {
                colorContainer.append('<button style="background-color: ' +this+ ' "> &nbsp; </button>');
            });

        var $modalHtml = $('<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> '+
                            '<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">' +
                                '<div class="modal-content" id=modal-colors> ' +
                                '</div> ' +
                            '</div> ' +
                        '</div>');
        $modalHtml.find('#modal-colors').append(colorContainer);
        $modalHtml.on('click', 'button' , function(){opts.onChanged($(this).attr('style'));})
        this.parent().append($modalHtml);
        return this.each(function(index){
            $(this).attr("id","color-picker-" + index);
            $(this).attr("data-toggle","modal");
            $(this).attr("data-target",".bs-example-modal-sm");
        });
    };




}( jQuery ));

    $.fn.colorpicker.defaults = {
        colors : ["#000000", "#1A0000", "#330000", "#4C0000", "#660000", "#800000", "#990000"],
        onChanged: function(rgb){}
};
```

and is called thus:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $( ".colorpicker" ).colorpicker({onChanged:function(color){
      console.log(color)
    }});

  </script>
```

http://joe-riggs.com/color/

Any other code criticisms welcome as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to me that you would want to fix this by properly setting the scope of `this` on the call to `opts.onChanged`.  Basically, you would want to make it so that the implementer of the plugin could do something like...

```
$( ".colorpicker" ).colorpicker({onChanged:function(color){
  $(this).css('background-color', color);
}});
```

In order to make that work, you'd need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call .  Something like

```
$.fn.colorpicker = function(options) {
    $(this).each(function(){
      var self = this;
      var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.colorpicker.defaults, options );
      var colorContainer = $('<ul/>').attr('id', 'container');
          $(opts.colors).each( function( index) {
              colorContainer.append('<button style="background-color: ' +this+ ' "> &nbsp; </button>');
          });

      var $modalHtml = $('<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> '+
                          '<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">' +
                              '<div class="modal-content" id=modal-colors> ' +
                              '</div> ' +
                          '</div> ' +
                      '</div>');
      $modalHtml.find('#modal-colors').append(colorContainer);
      $modalHtml.on('click', 'button' , function(){
          opts.onChanged.call(self, $(this).attr('style'));
      });
      this.parent().append($modalHtml);
      return this.each(function(index){
          $(this).attr("id","color-picker-" + index);
          $(this).attr("data-toggle","modal");
          $(this).attr("data-target",".bs-example-modal-sm");
      });
  });
};
```

This would make it so that `this` inside of the onChanged callback is the modal, and the implementing code could traverse inside of the modal to do whatever it wants.

Comment: TypeError: this.find(...).style is not a function. After some research, Im wondering if I need to rethink my plugin model - this looks promising,
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/
 thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I had a small typo.  It should be `.css` instead of `.style`.  I'm updating the answer.

Comment: To your link on SM - the same scoping problem would exist, although in general, it does make sense to follow better conventions for plugin development.

Comment: Perhaps I have a typo somewhere, but your code seems to be updating the colors in the modal buttons and not the original button caller

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question.  The code is written to change the modal button background color.  By "button caller", I'm getting you mean the `.colorpicker`.  I'm updating my answer to accomplish that.

Comment: Now its's setting all the button's on the page to the color. Maybe I have the wrong approach here. Is there a better design pattern or example I can reference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66044/discussion-between-bbonifield-and-jriggs).